# How to prove using Mean value theorem $3^x-2^x >(1.5)^x, \:\forall x \geq 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function, monotone-functions, mean-value-theorem

> > How to prove using Mean value theorem $3^x-2^x >(1.5)^x, \:\forall x \geq 2$

I did using the following way:

Suffice it to prove that $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x<1, \:\forall x \geq 2$$
Consider the function: $$\begin{aligned}
 & f(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x-1 \\
 & \Rightarrow  f^{\prime}(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x \ln \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x \ln \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)<0
\end{aligned}$$
Thus $f$ is monotone decreasing in $[2, \infty)$. Thus $$f(x) < f(2)<0 \Rightarrow f(x)<0 \Rightarrow 3^x-2^x>\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Alternatively one can argue that for $x \ge 2$
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x = \frac 1 4 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x-2}+\frac 4 9 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{x-2} \le \frac 1 4 + \frac 4 9  = \frac{25}{36} < 1 \, .
$$